# Mod Rewrite - on Nameless Get Parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current URL: www.domain.com/folder/site.php?25

Goal: www.domain.com/folder/site/25

I'm trying to rewrite the given URL to display the GET Parameter to a subfolder but until now I haven't found a proper way of doing so due to  the "nameless" variable.

Any ideas?

I'm not sure but in the .htaccess in the root Directory which is redirecting

domain.com/%% -> www.domain.com/%%

may be a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)